# permanent sigabrt at QApplication constructor when previously run ok

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, qt-creator, qt5.5

I am getting sigabrt right at the beginning of `main()` when I call:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);//here
...
```

This is the backtrace

```
>~"#0  0x00007ffff1293cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56\n"
>~"#1  0x00007ffff12970d8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89\n"
>~"#2  0x00007ffff213a0be in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
>~"#3  0x00007fffe78f7956 in QXcbConnection::QXcbConnection(QXcbNativeInterface*, bool, unsigned int, char const*) () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5\n"
>~"#4  0x00007fffe78fb066 in QXcbIntegration::QXcbIntegration(QStringList const&, int&, char**) () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5\n"
>~"#5  0x00007fffe7c0e39b in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so\n"
>~"#6  0x00007ffff2e5f762 in QPlatformIntegrationFactory::create(QString const&, QStringList const&, int&, char**, QString const&) () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5\n"
>~"#7  0x00007ffff2e6a9a8 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5\n"
>~"#8  0x00007ffff2e6b75d in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5\n"
>~"#9  0x00007ffff233da36 in QCoreApplication::init() () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
>~"#10 0x00007ffff233da96 in QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5\n"
>~"#11 0x00007ffff2e6d9a9 in QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(QGuiApplicationPrivate&) () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5\n"
>~"#12 0x00007ffff5ca392d in QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) () from /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5\n"
>~"#13 0x0000000000435889 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffec48) at ..../gui/main.cpp:14\n"
```

Previously the code was working ok(few minutes ago), I checked the md5 of libraries and compared with another PC (with same libs, running app alright) - no differences found.

I have found some [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1451545), but not sure if its connected.

I created new Qt project and its running ok - the `main()` looks the same (different includes, library dependencies).

Any ideas what shall I try next?

UPDATE:

I swear I havent changed anything, I checked with git diff - empty. This commit I am using for long time - it ran perfectly for days.

This is the message it displays:

> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Also - when I run from terminal ./app its running fine,
when run from gdb its running fine..

but cannot run from QtCreator-gdb or just without gdb from QtCreator(Ctrl+R)..

And now its making the same error at another computer - freshly installed Qt 5.5, freshly built, also build another libraries freshly..
then I removed whole shadow dir and rebuild and the error is gone.. weird.

I did the same `rm -rf shadow-dir/*` and run qmake and build on my original computer - same error.

Comment: Fully clean and rebuild.

Comment: It is not just a crash it is fatal exit (`QMessageLogger::fatal`): error message and abort. You should see some useful console message.

Comment: @SimonKraemer where do you think I have the backtrace

Comment: @bowdzone done, didnt helped(check update)

Comment: @OrestHera added the message to question

Comment: If it is the full message then your display name is empty. Check your project `Run Environment` variables. Print `QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().toStringList();` before `QApplication`. It should have something like `"DISPLAY=:0"`. To reproduce such abort I can manually set empty value to this variable in Qt project settings. Check its value in shell: `echo $DISPLAY`. In Qt project it should be the same.

Comment: It is also possible to provide manually empty display name from command line by running application as `./app-binary -display " "`.

Comment: @OrestHera - your suggestion solved the problem - I must have accidently changed in Project Settings -> Run Environment -> the base environment dropdow to "Clean environment" .. please add this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display` means that the application failed to connect to X Display. In that case the name of the display that it was trying to connect is empty (the name should follow the message).

The display name can be passed to the application by the environment variable `DISPLAY` or it can be overwritten by the application command line argument `-display ' '`:

```
./app-binary -display ' '
```

Check your proper `DISPLAY` value in the shell:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

Check the value of that variable in your application during run time before `QApplication app(argc, argv);` in Qt Creator by printing:

```
qDebug() << qgetenv("DISPLAY");
// or
qDebug() << QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().toStringList();
```

That print should contain something like `"DISPLAY=:0"` (the same value as during execution from the shell).

The Qt creator project options can overwrite system environment.